# What causes this error? 'You have requested a non-existent service "user.private_tempstore"'

Tags: 9, upgrading

I recently upgraded a site to Drupal 9. For content types that have media type as PDF documents, now I am not able to edit or save any uploaded pdf file. The drupal log shows this error.

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "user.private_tempstore". in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 157 of /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).

Has anyone come across this issue? I am not sure what is causing this error. Any guidance to resolve this issue please?

Comment: You can't debug this without a full error message. For Drupal 9 you have to enable the display of full error messages. Or use the current Drupal 10 version which displays log entries by default with a full stack trace. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/317940/how-to-debug-drupal-especially-when-no-webserver-logs-and-php-logs-are-available

Answer (score 1):

Yes, other people have come across this. You can find them by searching the Internet for ‘You have requested a non-existent service "user.private_tempstore"’. It means that you did not complete the preparatory work for upgrading. A module or theme on the site is not compatible with Drupal 9. `user.private_tempstore` was [deprecated in 2018](https://www.drupal.org/node/2935639).

It is not possible to say more in this answer without more information from you. But here is a tip: search the site code for “user.private_tempstore”.

Further I will mention that at the time I write this, Drupal 9 is end-of-life. It isn’t safe to use. You should move to Drupal 10 as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes it was due to "user.private_tempstore" in a custom module. I will soon be moving to Drupal 10